# How to remove terminated manager's DirectReports from Active Directory through PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I created a script to clear terminated user's manager in Active Directory. But want to remove his direct reportees through PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

The `Reports` attribute is a *linked* attribute, and its forward link is the `Manager` attribute.

Remove (or replace) the manager in the `Manager` attribute of the users and the `Reports` values will disappear automatically

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mathias R. Jessen. I have a script to clean the manager field as "Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Manager $null" But, still it doesn't like to go away.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to clear Direct Reports from all users in a specific OU. It creates a list of the Manager's direct reports, and then loops through that list and nulls the Manager property. Run the script with -WhatIf to see the accounts that will be affected.

```
$TSManagerList = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Tombstone,DC=Contoso" -Properties directreports, description | where{$_.directreports -ne ""}).samaccountname | sort

foreach($TSManager in $TSManagerList)
{
    $DirReportList = (Get-ADUser $TSManager -Properties directreports).directreports
    foreach($DirReport in $DirReportList)
    {
        $DirReportSam = (Get-ADUser -Filter * | where{$_.distinguishedname -eq $DirReport}).samaccountname
        Set-ADUser -Identity $DirReportSam -Manager $null -WhatIf 
    }
}
```